# Receiving a null pointer exception upon receiving data from the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, struts2

I have list of events stored in my database, but when I try to retrieve them all I get is a fat null pointer exception even though the results are there.

Here is my Service Class for the events

```
@Transactional
public class EventServices {
    // So Spring can inject the session factory
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory value) {
        sessionFactory = value;
    }

    // Shortcut for sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    public Session sess() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return sess().createQuery("from Event").list();
    }
}
```

Here is my ActionSupport Class

```
public class EventAction extends ActionSupport {

    protected EventServices eventServices;

    protected String redirectUrl;

    public String getRedirectUrl() {
        return redirectUrl;
    }

    public void setRedirectUrl(String redirectUrl) {
        this.redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    }

    public void setEventServices(EventServices eventServices) {
        this.eventServices = eventServices;
    }
}
```

My Event Action Class(Listing.java)

```
public class Listing extends EventAction{
    public String execute(){
        events = eventServices.getEvents();
        return "success";
    }

    List<Event> events;

    public List<Event> getEvents(){ return events; }
}
```

A fragment from the view (Listing.jsp)

```
<s:iterator value="events">
  <form action='Delete.action'>
    <input type='hidden' name=id value='<s:property value="id" />' />
    <input type='submit' value='-' title='Delete' />
  </form>
  <form action='Attendance.action'>
    <input type='hidden' name=id value='<s:property value="id" />' />
    <input type='submit' value='A' title='Attendance' />
  </form>
  <s:property value="name" />
  <br>
</s:iterator>
```

And I don't know if this will help this is my struts config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> <!-- set to false for prod -->

    <package name="events" namespace="/events" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*" class="actions.events.{1}">
            <result>/views/events/{1}.jsp</result>
            <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${redirectUrl}</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="root-redirect" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*">
            <result type = "redirect">events/Listing.action</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

And Application context xml that manages the lifecycle of sessionFactory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Springs Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id ="transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Inject my business services class to the action -->
    <bean id="services" class ="services.Services" scope ="singleton">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="evemtservices" class ="services.EventServices" scope ="singleton">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And this is the error

```
Struts Problem Report
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   
File:   actions/events/Listing.java
Line number:    12
```

Complete Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    actions.events.Listing.execute(Listing.java:13)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:285)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you show complete error stack? seems like either the service is not getting injected in your action and how you are injecting your `eventServices` in your action class as there is one typo as `eventServices` and id is `evemtservices`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I posted the complete stacktrace, please recheck the question

Comment: have you cross verified the typo?? you have declared it as `evemtservices` while it is named as `eventservices` in you action class?

Comment: WOW! it finally worked!! it was just a spelling error. so does that mean that I the instance variable inside my action class should match the declaration  of my applicationContext.xml?

Comment: well in one point it should if you have made it auto wired by its name, in that case spring will search a property with same name u have in your xml file and if it not found it will ignore it, this was the case you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer based on comments:

Problem was typo based on which Spring was not able to inject Service in the action class.In bean definition of OP

```
<bean id="evemtservices" class ="services.EventServices" scope ="singleton">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
 </bean>
```

Id was declared as `evemtservices` while property being used in action class was named as `eventservices`.

Since no service was injected by Spring so method call was throwing null pointer.

Comment: can you provide more explanation here? since I can't the eventServices or The EventAction in the applicationContext.xml, how did Spring found out about the eventServices variable?

Comment: i believe you are using struts2-spring plugin, see plugin doc to find out dependencies being injected http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/spring-plugin.html